# Где добавить свой текст (ссылку) для корзины Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress

Страница корзина и страница оформление заказа. Не могу найти файл(-ы) в котором(-ых) нужно дописать текст (ссылки произвольные) в те места, которые отметил на скринах.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает.
Спасибо заранее!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тут](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) вы можете посмотреть структуру шаблонов woocommerce по версиям. Папка шаблонов корзины - checkout. Ищите и обрящете.

Answer (score 0):

спасибо! [@Kirill Korushkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/236197/kirill-korushkin)

```
/ wp-content / plugins / woocommerce / templates / checkout
```

и

```
/ wp-content / plugins / woocommerce / templates / cart
```